# error php foreach in html input type select

Tags: php, loops, foreach, backend

I have a problem, I have an array of contacts that I send from the controller to the view and when it comes to going through it with a pos loop, everything goes well, but the problem lies when I try to interact within a select type input, creating for each contact a  `<option>` iterates but does not access the values

```
 <select id="members" name="members[]" class="form-select" multiple required>
    <option value="tu" selected>Tú</option>
    <?php foreach ($contacts as $contact) : ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $contact[$id] ?>"><?php echo $contact[$username] ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

</select>
```

this does work but outside the input select -->

```
<?php foreach ($contacts as $contact) : ?>
    <?php debug($contact); //function for print data
    ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

this is what the date looks like -->

[image: data]

Comment: Is the screenshot showing `$contacts` or `$contact`?

Comment: Typo: `$contact[$id]` should be `$contact['id']`, and similar for `username`.

Comment: Also, if the output you show is the result of `var_dump($contact)`, then the contact list is in `$contacts[0]`, not `$contacts`. I don't know why you have the extra level of nesting, but you'll need to account for it.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 different method to get value.

1. using key name with "square brackets []":

   ```html
   <select id="members" name="members[]" class="form-select" multiple required>
       <option value="tu" selected>Tú</option>
       <?php foreach ($contacts as $contact) : ?>
           <option value="<?php echo $contact['id'] ?>"><?php echo $contact['username'] ?></option>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
   </select>
   ```
2. using key name with "arrow ->":

   ```html
   <select id="members" name="members[]" class="form-select" multiple required>
       <option value="tu" selected>Tú</option>
       <?php foreach ($contacts as $contact) : ?>
           <option value="<?php echo $contact->id ?>"><?php echo $contact->username ?></option>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
   </select>
   ```
3. using key name with "dots . ":

   ```html
   <select id="members" name="members[]" class="form-select" multiple required>
       <option value="tu" selected>Tú</option>
          <?php foreach ($contacts as $contact) : ?>
           <option value="<?php echo $contact.id ?>"><?php echo $contact.username ?></option>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
   </select>
   ```

Those all methods are same but we can get value using this methods simple.

Comment: wow, that was it, how silly I feel not realizing it, I think it was because of the late hours in which I was doing it hahaha, thank you very much